# Update Chat Dynamically in Quickblox

Tags: ios, swift, chat, quickblox

I've searched in quickblox docs but couldn't find any delegate methods for retrieving chat messages dynamically. I have a view controller with table view where the cell contains dynamic chat messages. It needs to be updated in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at our [chat sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat). In our class [ChatViewController.m](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample-chat/sample-chat/ViewController/ChatViewController.m) you can find methods for handling incoming messages - QMChatServiceDelegate.
Or you can use methods of QBChatDelegate

```
- (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message fromDialogID:(NSString *)dialogID
{
}

- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
{

}

- (void)chatDidReceiveSystemMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is QBChatDelegate available for Swift, as I'm unable to sefine delegate methods of QBChatDelegate in Swift file

Comment: It's available in Swift too. take a look at our [swift sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat-swift) and you need to add a bridge header. Look at [this instruction](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework).

Answer (score 1):

I found [Chat in dialog](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_in_dialog) in code examples

It specifies some delegate methods:

- for private messages

  ```
  QBChat.instance().addDelegate(self)

  ...

  func chatDidReceiveMessage(message: QBChatMessage!) {

  }
  ```
- for group messages

  ```
  var groupChatDialog: QBChatDialog = ...
  groupChatDialog.joinWithCompletionBlock { (error: NSError?) -> Void in

  }

  ...

  - (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message fromDialogId:(NSString *)dialogId{

  }
  ```

You should check `QBChatDialog` for a delegate property or method because it seems there's no code for subscription to message delegate, see what happens in dialog initialisation `var groupChatDialog: QBChatDialog = ...`
I didn't find the detailed API :(